# Why isn't my Logcat displaying any log?

Tags: java, android, service

**Main.java**

```
Package com.first.service;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Myservice.class);
        startService(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Myservice extends Service{
    public Myservice(){

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service Started");
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

I am new to android services and I want to create a new Service application, but logcat isn't displaying anything.

Please help me and suggest me, if there is anything wrong with the code.
I am new to StackOverflow.

See the image to have clear idea:

[image]

Comment: Did you search for your 'TAG' in the logcat?

Comment: Yes I have done everything it isn't showing anything.

Comment: See the image included. It isn't showing anything.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html):
Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse has ended. You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible.

Comment: The reason you don't see any logs is not in your code, but rather in IDE you use. ADT Plugin for eclipse is no longer supported because Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have downloaded present version of android studio